# Is it possible to match any number of specific characters within a term?

Tags: java, regex

I have some user input that I am trying to match against however I strip out special characters such as `'^-` etc. I would like to know if it is possible to provide a specific set of characters to match or "ignore". So if the list contained `"^-"` and the term was `PRM`, `P^^R---^M` would be a match but `PROM` would not since `O` is not in the set of "allowed" characters.

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: Would love an explanation of the downvotes, happy to rephrase if the question needs it.

Comment: It's possible, but clunky. You'd have to do something like `P[^-]*R[^-]*M`. A far better solution is to just remove those characters from your string before applying a regex.

Comment: I can probably do that, but i need to preserve the string, regex would make my life easier, but if its not appropriate I can move on.

Comment: Then I would recommend making a copy of the string before removing the special characters, THEN applying the regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Java 8, you can use [`String.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to join the individual characters from the term with character groups representing one or more of your special characters, i.e. something like `[^-]*`, but with regex special character escaped.

```
String term = "PRM";
String special = "^-";

String delimiter = "[" + Pattern.quote(special) + "]*";
String regex = String.join(delimiter, term.split(""));

System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "PROM"));      // --> false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, "P^^R---^M")); // --> true
```

Alternatively, you could also [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) the special chars with `""` and check for equality:

```
System.out.println(term.equals("PROM".replaceAll(delimiter, "")));      // --> false
System.out.println(term.equals("P^^R---^M".replaceAll(delimiter, ""))); // --> true
```

Comment: so no way to globally list it, i guess that makes sense. thanks for the help.

Comment: I just meant instead of inserting the list of "specials" between each character, to provide it in a global way a single time. I suppose it doesn't actually matter though.

Comment: @kgrad See my second approach, just replacing all those characters with nothing and then comparing. This might in fact be simpler.

Comment: The second approach would definitely work, but in my scenario i need to preserve the original term.

Comment: @kgrad That should not be a problem. `replaceAll` does not modify the original string, it creates a new one. Strings are unmodifyable.

Comment: I need to retain the original string - with the special characters. The part that matched.

Comment: @kgrad I still don't see the problem. You can call `replaceAll` on the string and thus create a copy of the string with special chars removed, test with that copy, and then continue working with the original string.